# Mostrar array json en select javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

Tengo una función del evento change de un select en javascript, el cual envió el id del cliente y me retorna correctamente un json de los autos asociado al cliente. Como podría hacer para mostrar el resultado del json al **select autos**, ya que me muestra todos los autos registrados y no los específicos del json.

Codigo select change:

```
//SELECT CLIENTE Y OBTENER VEHICULOS ASOCIADOS AL CLIENTE
client_id1.change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{route('get_cars_by_id')}}",
            method: 'GET',
            data:{
                client_id: client_id1.val(),
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $("#car_id1").val(data.result[0].id);              
        }
    });
});
```

Metodo que retorna el json

```
public function get_cars_by_id(Request $request){

    
    if ($request->ajax()) {   
        $result = Car::where('client_id','=', $request->client_id)->get();
        
        return response()->json(['result'=>$result]);
    }

   
}
```

Select Autos al que deseo enviar el resultado del JSON obtenido

```
 <select class="form-control" name="car_id" id="car_id1">
        @foreach ($cars as $car)
        <option value="{{$car->id}}">{{$car->id}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

primero que todo borra el select de carros, lo dejas asi

```
<select class="form-control" name="car_id" id="car_id1">
       
    </select>
```

luego cuando recuperas el listado de carros en ajax haces el append a la data que recibes de tu back-end asi

```
    $('#client_id1').change(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{route('get_cars_by_id')}}",
                method: 'GET',
                data:{
                    client_id: $(this).val(),
                },
                success: function(data){
               let cars = $("#car_id1");
               cars.empty();
                    $(data.result).each(function(index, value){ 
                        cars.append(`<option value="${value.id}">${value.laPropiedadDelModelo}</option>`);
                    })
                                
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, funciono lo que me mencionaste, solo una consulta, la primera vez que selecciono un cliente, carga correctamente el select de autos, pero cuando quiero seleccionar otro cliente, el select de autos no me actualiza laPropiedadDelModelo y se me acumula el resultado del id anterior.

Comment: ahí te edite la solución, si te sirvió por favor marca la pregunta como resuelta y pon el voto a favor en mi respuesta, saludos

Comment: Excelente amigo! solo el único inconveniente que tengo ahora es que solo me trae un carro por cliente, ejemplo cuando hago un console.log(data) el array me trae dos objetos pero en el select carros solo me aparece uno. Leí de una propiedad $.map pero me da error.

Comment: jajjaa si perdon, ya vuelvo a editar la respuesta, por favor marcala como resuelta para que personas que tengan el mismo problema se puedan guiar

Comment: Funciona perfecto, gracias!